# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imwrite' img data type = 17 is not supported

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to use a picture to create a Histograms Equalization. I'm imported image and cv2 already but there are still having an issue.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv



path = r'C:\Users\Lilly\Downloads\lena_color.jpg'
img = cv.imread(path,0)
equ = cv.equalizeHist(img)
res = np.hstack((img,equ)) 
cv.imwrite('res.png',res)
```

These is an error.

```
PS C:\Users\Lilly> & C:/Users/Lilly/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/Lilly/Downloads/Equalization.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lilly\Downloads\Equalization.py", line 17, in <module>
    cv.imwrite('res.png',res)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imwrite'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - img data type = 17 is not supported
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

Comment: img data type = 17 means the image type is: `CV_8SC3`. You need to convert it to `CV_8UC3` to save with `imwrite`.

Comment: Try to add `res = res.view(np.uint8)` before `imwrite`. Although I could not reproduce. In my case `res` was a `uint8` image.

Comment: I tried and the result is "c:\Users\Lilly\Downloads\Equalization.py", line 18, in <module>
    res = res.view(np.uint8)
  File "C:\Users\Lilly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_internal.py", line 549, in _view_is_safe
    raise TypeError("Cannot change data-type for object array.")
TypeError: Cannot change data-type for object array.

Comment: How about converting with: `res = res.astype(uint8)`  (instead of using `view`) ?

Comment: `path = r'C:\Users\Lilly\Downloads\lena_color.jpg'
img = cv.imread(path,0)
equ = cv.equalizeHist(img)
res = np.hstack((img,equ)) 
res = res.astype(np.uint8)
cv.imwrite('res.png',res)` the result is PS C:\Users\Lilly> & C:/Users/Lilly/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/Lilly/Downloads/Equalization.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lilly\Downloads\Equalization.py", line 18, in <module>
    res = res.astype(np.uint8)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: `path = r'C:\Users\Lilly\Downloads\lena_color.jpg'
img = cv.imread(path,0)
equ = cv.equalizeHist(img)
res = np.hstack((img,equ)) 
res = res.astype(uint8)
cv.imwrite('res.png',res)` the result is PS C:\Users\Lilly> & C:/Users/Lilly/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/Lilly/Downloads/Equalization.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lilly\Downloads\Equalization.py", line 18, in <module>
    res = res.astype(uint8)
NameError: name 'uint8' is not defined

Comment: This work for me. img = cv.imread('lena_color.jpg',0)
equ = cv.equalizeHist(img)
res = np.hstack((img,equ)) 
cv.imwrite('res.png',res)

Comment: Is that Equalization.py you saved it?

Comment: @toyotaSupra the result File "c:\Users\Lilly\Downloads\Equalization.py", line 16, in <module>
    cv.imwrite('res.png',res)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imwrite'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - img data type = 17 is not supported
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. make sure you actually managed to load the image. `assert img is not None`

Comment: Thank you everyone! I can solved it now by using a new picture from other source.

Answer (score 3):

`imread()` failed. It returned `None`. The file could not be found or the file is corrupt.

`equalizeHist()` does not complain. It simply returns `None` too.

`res` now becomes `array([None, None], dtype=object)`

`imwrite()` can't handle this and complains with this error message.

**The fix** is to make sure `imread()` succeeds. Figure out if the file actually exists.

```
assert os.path.exists(path)
img = cv.imread(path)
assert img is not None
```

Comment: Resistance is futile

Comment: I've had to see this "type 17" thing one to many times now. never gave it much thought before... but it's a problem. Bug report: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/23106

Comment: Maybe the examples provided on OpenCV website should also be bug reported so that they stop setting poor examples, e.g. 1) `cv.imread('...',0)` using ugly constants and 2) `cv.imread()` but no following `assert`. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html

Comment: screw reporting. I'll just do a pull request for that. all the newbies copying that "style" is driving me nuts! I wasn't aware that official tutorials themselves are in that state. -- good catch with that mistake in my answer @DanMašek

Comment: OP's code is literally from https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html so the docs are definitely to blame for carrying on through the error until it's unrecognizable